# panic-full ips log; Sleep Wake hang detected; iPhone accident restart

Tags: iphone, ios, kernel-panic

```
"panicString" : "panic(cpu 0 caller 0xfffffff017722ccc): \"Sleep\/Wake hang detected\"n
```

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| build | 12.4.9 (16G201) |
| product | iPhone7,2 |
| OS | 12.4.8 |
| model | iPhone 6 |
| capacity | 32 GB |

How to check the log is which software/app or hardware cause force restart my iPhone?
Any other information need provide?